# displaying output in a single line

Tags: shell-script, echo

How to display output in a sinlge line.

My code is:

```
echo "total directories:" && find $DIR -type d | wc -l

echo "total files:" && find $DIR -type f | wc -l
```

output displays as

```
total directories:
145
total files:
254
```

I want to display like:

```
total directories: 145
total files: 254
```

Comment: `echo -n ...` to suppress the printing of the newline character.

Comment: `printf "%s " "Total files:" $(find $DIR -type f | wc -l)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` instead:

```
printf 'total directories: %s\n' "$(find "$DIR" -type d | wc -l)"
printf 'total files: %s\n' "$(find "$DIR" -type f | wc -l)"
```

Note that this will output wrong result if any directories or files contains newline in their name.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
echo "total directories: $(find "$DIR" -type d | wc -l)"
echo "total files: $(find "$DIR" -type f | wc -l)"
```